# how to use '$lookup' in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have written a query in mongo shell that goes something like this

```
ACollection.aggregate([
    {
        '$match':{
            'Date':curr_date,
            'inTime':{'$exists':True}
        }
    },
    { '$lookup':
        {
           'from': "detections",
           'localField': "_id",
           'foreignField': "AttendanceId",
           'as': "userDetections"
        }
    }
])
```

I am trying to convert this into a mongoose version

```
const userGeoPoints = async(date) => {
    const geoData = await Attendance.aggregate([
      {
          $match:{
              'Date':formatTimeToIso(date),
              'inTime':{'$exists':true}
          }
      },
      { $lookup:
          {
             from: "detections",
             localField: "_id",
             foreignField: "AttendanceId",
             as: "userDetections"
          }
      }
  ])
  return geoData
}
```

But this is just giving empty results

Comment: Lookup syntax is the same, it should works, take care about the name of the collection. How is your mongoose model? The third parameter is an explicit collection name. Also check if `$match` stage works ok.

Comment: is `typeof curr_date` the same as `typeof formatTimeToISO(date)`?